# Will a large number of tables (although of small size) in a database affect the performance of mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, session

I have implemented my android app in such a way that session tables are handled by MySQL memory tables. A session table is created for each active user to keep the speed high. This led to a large number of session tables for active users. Does the presence of those hundreds of sessions tables affect the performance of MySQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are deleted for inactive sessions, then I don't see a particular problem with the proliferation of "hundreds" of tables.  Hundreds of tables should be fine.  Hundreds of thousands becomes another issue.

I do question whether you have a good approach and whether the overhead for each session is worth it (this is slightly different from your question which is about the number of tables).  Creating and dropping tables incurs overhead -- system tables need to be maintained and locks on such tables slow things down.

In general, the way to handle such situations is with rows in existing tables.  There are circumstances where this isn't appropriate.  For instance, if the session tables have significant user-defined content so the structures are quite different.  If the structures are the same, then there is little reason to have multiple tables, and lots of reason to put the data into a single table (perhaps partitioned by session id if deleting the rows quickly is a concern).